# Eas build fails with error Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to create an APK from react native expo application but upon doing the command to generate the apk (eas build), I run into the following error :

> [stderr]
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> [stderr]
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> [stderr]
>
> Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'.
>
> [stderr]
>
> > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
>
> [stderr]
>
> > Compilation error. See log for more details
>
> [stderr]
>
> - Try:
>
> [stderr]
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>
> [stderr]
>
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> [stderr]
>
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> [stderr]
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> [stderr]
>
> BUILD FAILED in 6m 32s
>
> Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run
> gradlew" phase for more information.

I thought the error could be from splash in the app.json file but I can't see what's wrong in it.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Talky",
    "slug": "talky",
    "scheme": "com.bertdelaspeed.talky",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/Talky_logo.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/Talky_splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }

  }
}
```

Here are the dependencies installed :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I figured out is to first do:

```
1. npx expo prebuild
```

That should generate an android directory then you can do

```
2. CTRL + SHIFT + F (in Vs code or Search) and search 'expo-splash-screen'
```

You should find it in 3 places:
package.json, package-lock.json and node_modules

```
3. Delete it from all of those places and run your build command again
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed with out expo prebuild, by just upgrading to latest expo version or expo@~49.0.6

[Source](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1965#issuecomment-1660795254)

Answer (score 0):

Q: Execution failed for task ':expo-screen-capture:compileReleaseKotlin'

If I manually add this to build.gradle it works.

```
buildscript {
   ext {
       kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
   }
}
```

Details: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16907

Answer (score 0):

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 7m 29s
  Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

i had same error.

this helped me;

2. CTRL + SHIFT + F (in Vs code or Search) and search 'expo-splash-screen'
3. Delete it from all of those places and run your build command again

thanks